# Domino + Postini + Dynamic IP

Tags: ibm-domino

I was wondering if it's possible to use Google's Postini service with Domino which is set-up on a server that has a Dynamic public IP address?

If not, what options are available here?

Comment: How do you handle the MX records for your domain, if you have your server behind a dynamic IP?

Comment: pointing to dynamic dns at the moment - dyndns.com - which again is not a good idea therefore I was hoping to move to something else - any suggestion or ideas!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically: get a fixed IP address. Dynamic address ranges are often in blacklists, ... so they can't send email to lots of destinations anyway. It's not worth the hassle for a company.

Comment: That's the reason for going to Postini, since not only will they clean my email, but also handle my MX records, but they don't accept dynamic ip sites, so was wondering what's the alternative.

Comment: How about a third party smtp authentication service? So the outbound messages are sent via third party service? Then setting up a foreign domain document within Domino?